# How to identify if a recent pull had changes inside a directory

Tags: bash, git

I currently have a git project with the structure:

```
z.txt
foo/a.txt
foo/b.txt
```

using bash how can I identify after running `$ git pull` that either `a.txt` and/or `b.txt` (i.e anything under the `foo` directory) have been altered?

Comment: `git pull` should tell you what gets updated as it runs. Can you be more specific?

Comment: Sorry I am after a shell script including which git commands to use to identify the above. I want something more specific then `if git pull | grep "foo/" then; ...` unless that is the only answer

Answer (score 2):

## A. If you already pulled

### `git diff`

You can use `git diff` and specifically:

- `git diff commit1..commit2 --name-only`; or
- `git diff commit1..commit2 --name-status`

The following descriptions are from the [doco](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#Documentation/git-diff.txt---name-only).

> --name-only
>
> Show only names of changed files.
>
> --name-status
>
> Show only names and status of changed files. See the description of the --diff-filter option on what the status letters mean.

---

`git pull` tells you the commit ids it merges/fast-forwards:

```
/mnt/c/git/repo666 (develop)>git pull
Updating f86907f7a..a708dcfe8
```

In this case the command would be:

```
git diff f86907f7a..a708dcfe8 --name-status
```

---

### `git log`

To see differences per commit you could use `git log` with `--name-only` or `--name-status`.

## B. Before a pull

If you haven't pulled and you want a peek at the potential changes you can `git fetch` the branch (not `pull`) and compare the local copy of the remote branch your current branch.

```
/mnt/c/git/repo666(develop)>git fetch // not git pull
(...)
/mnt/c/git/repo666(develop)>git status
On branch develop
Your branch is behind 'origin/develop' by 3 commits, and can be fast-forwarded.
  (use "git pull" to update your local branch)

nothing to commit, working tree clean
/mnt/c/git/Platform (develop)>git diff develop origin/develop --name-status
```

*(Please note I used `git diff branch origin/branch` and not `git diff origin/branch` so that is shown in the desired order i.e. if the file was added in `origin/develop` we want to see it as added not deleted.)*

---

## Note on `git pull` output

Please note that the output of `git pull` contains added and renamed files twice

```
Fast-forward
 ...
 src/Folder1/Services/File1.cs                                      |   30 +
 src/Folder1/Services/File2.cs                                      |    7 +
 ...
 src/Folder1/ViewModels/XViewModel.cs                               |    8 +-
 ...
 src/{Abc.Common/Services => Abc/Contracts/Area1}/Area1File1.cs     |    7 +-
 ...
 89 files changed, 7254 insertions(+), 4897 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 src/Folder1/Services/File1.cs
 create mode 100644 src/Folder1/Services/File2.cs
 ...
 rename src/{Abc.Common/Services => Abc/Contracts/Area1}/Area1File1.cs (83%)
 ...
```

Comment: Do you know how I could export `commit1` and `commit2` into a bash variable?

Answer (score 0):

We can get closer than what @tymtam suggests, if you're willing to do things before you run `git pull`.

Get the SHA for your current head and save it:

```sh
sha="$(git rev-parse HEAD)"
```

Next, run the pull:

```sh
git pull
```

Finally, compare `foo` on your new HEAD to what you had before:

```sh
git diff --stat $sha -- foo
```

Note, if you have uncommitted changes, those will be included in what `git diff` reports, so you can always run `git stash` before your diff command to hide them, and then `git stash pop` to get them back.

Comment: I think a `git fetch` followed by `diff branch origin/branch` is simpler. I updated my answer.